# Yii2 - Gridview play next song

Tags: html, audio, gridview, yii2

**I have a Gridview in my Yii2 app that loads a HTML5 audio player for each mp3 audio file stored in a folder. Every row of the Gridview has it's own audio player. It does that because the file path of each mp3 file is stored in the database.**

Here it is:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'nome',
        //'ficheiro',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=> function ($data){                      
                        return "<audio controls='controls'>
                        <source src='" . $data->ficheiro . "' type='audio/mp3' />
                        </audio>";
                        },
        ],
        //'dummy1',
        //'dummy2',
        // 'dummy3',
        // 'dummy4',
        // 'dummy5',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => ''],
    ],
]); ?>
```

**At the end of one file playing is there a way to activate the next row audio player and start play the next file?**

I've searched but only encounter the solution to play the next file in the same audio player file playlist. Not to activate the next audio player with it's own file.

**Many thanks for a possible solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this snippet can help you:

```
$(function(){
    var audio = $('audio');
    audio.on('ended', function(){
        endedTrackIndex = audio.index(this);
        if((endedTrackIndex + 1) >= audio.size()) {
            return true;
        }

        nextTrack = audio.get(endedTrackIndex + 1);
        nextTrack.play();
    });
});
```

Read the [audio dom reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) about methods, properties and events available for *audio* element

Comment: SOLVED! The snippet has pointed me in the right way.
Many thanks Tony :)